# Cannot forward after response has been committed in java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have login JSP which will redirect to servlet called DisplayData which must check the user credentials and displays the data only for registered users. But it throws error called "Cannot forward after response has been committed". here is the servlet code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    HttpSession usersession = request.getSession(true);
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String query;
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet res;
    DatabaseConnection dbconn;

    String username="";
    String hiddenname = request.getParameter("hiddenname");

    if (hiddenname.equals("login"))
    {
        username = request.getParameter("username");
        //System.out.println(username);
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        // System.out.println(password);
        usersession.setAttribute("uname", username);
        usersession.setAttribute("upass", password);
        Connection con = dbconnection.getCon();
        System.out.println(con);
        PreparedStatement statemt = null;
        try {
            statemt = con.prepareStatement("select User_name,Password from login_details where User_name = ? and Password = ?");
            System.out.println(statemt);
            statemt.setString(1, username); // set input parameter 1
            statemt.setString(2, password); // set input parameter 2
            ResultSet rs = statemt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next() == false)
            {
                out.write("Invalid user name or password. Please press back button to login again");

            }
            else
            {
                String url="/index.jsp";
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    List lst=new ArrayList();
    String login_name,login_password;
    try
    {

        login_name=(String) session.getAttribute("uname");
        login_password=(String) session.getAttribute("upass");
        request.setAttribute("UserName", login_name);
        request.setAttribute("UserPassword", login_password);
        dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();
        conn=dbconn.setConnection();
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        query="select * from mpi";
        res=dbconn.getResultSet(query, conn);
        while(res.next())
        {

            lst.add(res.getString("UniqueID"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Phylum"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Family"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Genus"));
            lst.add(res.getString("NCBI_Taxnomy_ID"));
            lst.add(res.getString("16s_Sanger_seq"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Genome_Sequencing_Batch"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Stock_number"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Stock_Location"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Soil_batch"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Host"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Operator"));
            lst.add(res.getString("GPS_coordinates"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Greenhouse_or_Natural_sites"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Isolation_procedure"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Date_of_isolation"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Previous_Ids"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Compartment"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Publication"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Strain_Derivatives"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Growth_conditions"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Natural_antibiotic_resistance"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Colony_morphology"));
        }
        res.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally
    {
        request.setAttribute("UserData", lst);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayrecord.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        lst.clear();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

I don't know where the mistake is. Kindly help me.

Comment: You miss the "else" block in "if (hiddenname.equals("login"))" condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of forwards in your code. One example:

```
String url="/index.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Further down the code you have a block with `try/catch/finally`. Specifically you have the block

```
finally
{
    request.setAttribute("UserData", lst);
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayrecord.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    lst.clear();
    out.close();
}
```

When you forward a request it does not stop the execution in your method. Once it is done with the forward it will continue execution where you left off and you are having a guaranteed forward in the end with the `finally` block. The `finally` block will be executed no matter what happened earlier in your code. If you are first executing one of the forwards up in the top of your code, it will fail when you are hitting the `finally` block because then it is trying to forward the request a second time and that will cause the error you are experiencing.

Look closely at your full stack trace because it should indicate the exact line number where it is trying to use the response (in your case the forwards) a second time. You need to rearrange/rewrite your code so that you only execute one forward (at most).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked the full stack and I found the error points to "if (hiddenname.equals("login"))". the problem the servlet code does not check user credentials at all and directly redirtecs the login.jsp to displayrecord.jsp which I dont want. I want the servlet code to check for the credentials and then load the  data.

Comment: You probably need to look at your `finally` block more closely. What that block essentially does is that it will forward your request to `/displayrecord.jsp` no matter what happened earlier in the code and from your comment I understand that you do not want that. You should probably have that block in an if-statement rather than in a `finally` block. Also updated the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: I found my fault..I put the second of half of my code for displaying the records from database into else block after removing the multiple response.redirect and retaining only one in finally block and thu solved the issue..thanks for ur suggestion