# NullPointerException in java servlet while updating and deleting records

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I developed browser front end for displaying,editing and updating records from database. Previously I had different servlet for performing the Inserting, editing and Updating records. Now I want club all the servlets into a single servlet called "DisplayData" and I used hidden field respective in login.JSP form and in "edit.jsp" so that servlet can perform login operation or update operation based on the hidden parameter.

The code works fine for the login operation which allows only registered users  but when I try edit the record and update it, it shows the java.lang.Nullpointer exception. When I try to delete the record it shows the same error.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
HttpSession usersession = request.getSession(true);
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String query;
Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet res;
DatabaseConnection dbconn;

String username="";
String hiddenname = request.getParameter("hiddenname"); 
System.out.println(hiddenname);



    username = request.getParameter("username");
    System.out.println(username);
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    System.out.println(password);
    usersession.setAttribute("uname", username);
    usersession.setAttribute("upass", password);
    Connection con = dbconnection.getCon();
    System.out.println(con);
    PreparedStatement statemt = null;

    if (hiddenname.equals("login"))
            {

        try {
    statemt = con.prepareStatement("select User_name,Password from login_details where User_name = ? and Password = ?");
    System.out.println(statemt);
    statemt.setString(1, username);
    statemt.setString(2, password); 
    ResultSet rs = statemt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next() == false) 
            {
                out.write("Invalid user name or password. Please press back button to login again");

            }
        else
        {
            List lst=new ArrayList();       
            String login_name,login_password;
            try
            {

                    login_name=(String) session.getAttribute("uname");
                    login_password=(String) session.getAttribute("upass");
                    request.setAttribute("UserName", login_name);
                    request.setAttribute("UserPassword", login_password);
                    dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();        
                    conn=dbconn.setConnection();
                    stmt=conn.createStatement();
                    query="select * from mpi";
                    res=dbconn.getResultSet(query, conn);
                    while(res.next())
                    {

                        lst.add(res.getString("UniqueID"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Phylum"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Family"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Genus"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("NCBI_Taxnomy_ID"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("16s_Sanger_seq"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Genome_Sequencing_Batch"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Stock_number"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Stock_Location"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Soil_batch"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Host"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Operator"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("GPS_coordinates"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Greenhouse_or_Natural_sites"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Isolation_procedure"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Date_of_isolation"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Previous_Ids"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Compartment"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Publication"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Strain_Derivatives"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Growth_conditions"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Natural_antibiotic_resistance"));
                        lst.add(res.getString("Colony_morphology"));
                    }
                                res.close(); 
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();        
                }
                finally
                {
                    request.setAttribute("UserData", lst);
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayrecord.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                    lst.clear();
                    out.close();
                }
            }           
                    con.close();
    } 


            catch (SQLException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }

    else if(hiddenname.equals("update"))
    {
        String UniqueID,Phylum,Family,Genus,NCBI_Taxnomy_ID,s16_Sanger_seq,Genome_Sequencing_Batch,Stock_number,
        Stock_Location,Soil_batch,Host,Operator,GPS_coordinates,Greenhouse_or_Natural_sites,
        Isolation_procedure,Date_of_isolation,Previous_Ids,Compartment,Publication,Strain_Derivatives,Growth_conditions,
        Natural_antibiotic_resistance,Colony_morphology,Comments;   
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try{
            dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();        
            conn=dbconn.setConnection();
            System.out.println("conn");
            UniqueID=request.getParameter("UniqueID");
            Phylum=request.getParameter("Phylum");          
            Family=request.getParameter("Family");          
            Genus=request.getParameter("Genus");        
            NCBI_Taxnomy_ID=request.getParameter("NCBI_Taxnomy_ID");        
            s16_Sanger_seq=request.getParameter("s16_Sanger_seq");
            System.out.println(s16_Sanger_seq);
            Genome_Sequencing_Batch=request.getParameter("Genome_Sequencing_Batch");
            Stock_number=request.getParameter("Stock_number");
            Stock_Location=request.getParameter("Stock_Location");
            Soil_batch=request.getParameter("Soil_batch");
            Host=request.getParameter("Host");
            Operator=request.getParameter("Operator");
            GPS_coordinates=request.getParameter("GPS_coordinates");
            Greenhouse_or_Natural_sites=request.getParameter("Greenhouse_or_Natural_sites");
            Isolation_procedure=request.getParameter("Isolation_procedure");
            Date_of_isolation=request.getParameter("Date_of_isolation");
            Previous_Ids=request.getParameter("Previous_Ids");
            Compartment=request.getParameter("Compartment");
            Publication=request.getParameter("Publication");
            Strain_Derivatives=request.getParameter("Strain_Derivatives");
            Growth_conditions=request.getParameter("Growth_conditions");
            Natural_antibiotic_resistance=request.getParameter("Natural_antibiotic_resistance");
            Colony_morphology=request.getParameter("Colony_morphology");

            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            query="update mpi set Phylum='"+Phylum+"',Family='"+Family+"',Genus='"+Genus+"',NCBI_Taxnomy_ID='"+NCBI_Taxnomy_ID+"',16s_Sanger_seq='"+s16_Sanger_seq+"',Genome_Sequencing_Batch='"+Genome_Sequencing_Batch+"',Stock_number='"+Stock_number+"',Stock_Location='"+Stock_Location+"',Soil_batch='"+Soil_batch+"',Host='"+Host+"',Operator='"+Operator+"',GPS_coordinates='"+GPS_coordinates+"',Greenhouse_or_Natural_sites='"+Greenhouse_or_Natural_sites+"',Date_of_isolation='"+Date_of_isolation+"',Isolation_procedure='"+Isolation_procedure+"',Previous_Ids='"+Previous_Ids+"',Compartment='"+Compartment+"',Publication='"+Publication+"',Strain_Derivatives='"+Strain_Derivatives+"',Growth_conditions='"+Growth_conditions+"',Natural_antibiotic_resistance='"+Natural_antibiotic_resistance+"',Colony_morphology='"+Colony_morphology+"' where UniqueID='"+UniqueID+"'";
            System.out.println(query);
            int i=stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally{

            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayrecord.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            out.close();
        }


    }else if(hiddenname.equals("delete"))
    {
        try{
                                   id=request.getParameter("hidden_delete");
            System.out.println(id);
            dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();
            conn=dbconn.setConnection();
            System.out.println(conn);
            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println(stmt);
            query="delete from mpi where UniqueID="+id;
            int i=stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }finally{
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("DisplayData");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            out.close();
        }
    }
}}
```

Could anyone tell me were my mistake lies. 
Here is my JSP code for displayrecord.jsp

```
`<body><input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('table_id', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
<TABLE  id="table_id" align="Center" border="1px" width="80%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><b>UniqueID</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_uid" >
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="uid" id="uid">
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Phylum</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="phylum" id="phylum">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_phylum" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit"  value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Family</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="family" id="family">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_family" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Genus</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="genus" id="genus">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_genus" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>NCBI Taxonomy ID</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_taxid" >
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="taxid" id="taxid">
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>16s Sanger Seq</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="16ssangerseq" id="16ssangerseq">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_16ssangerseq" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit"  value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Genome Sequencing Batch</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="genomeseqbatch" id="genomeseqbatch">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_genomeseqbatch" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Stock number</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Stock_number" id="Stock number">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Stocknumber" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Stock Location</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input  type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_StockLocation" >
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Stock_Location" id="Stock Location">
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Soil batch</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Soil_batch" id="Soil batch">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Soilbatch" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit"  value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Host</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="host" id="host">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_host" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Operator</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="operator" id="operator">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_operator" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>GPS co-ordinates</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input  type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_GPS_coordinates" >
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="GPS_coordinates" id="GPS co-ordinates">
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Green House Sites</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Green_House_Sites" id="Green House Sites">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Green_House_Sites" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit"  value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Isolation procedure</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Isolation_procedure" id="Isolation procedure">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Isolation_procedure" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Date of isolation</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Date_of_isolation" id="Date of isolation">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Date_of_isolation" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Previous Ids</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Previous_Ids" >
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Previous_Ids" id="Previous_Ids">
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Compartment</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Compartment" id="Compartment">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Compartment" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit"  value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Publication</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Publication" id="Publication">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Publication" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Strain Derivatives</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Strain_Derivatives" id="Strain Derivatives">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Strain_Derivatives" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Growth conditions</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Growth_conditions" id="Growth conditions">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Growth_conditions" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit"  value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Natural antibiotic resistance</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Natural_antibiotic_resistance" id="Natural antibiotic resistance">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Natural_antibiotic_resistance" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th>
    <th><b>Colony morphology</b>
    <form action="SearchId" method="post">
    <input class="ignore" type="text" name="Colony_morphology" id="Colony morphology">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="hidden_Colony_morphology" >
    <input class="ignore" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fbody">
    <%Iterator itr;%>
    <%List data=(List) request.getAttribute("UserData");
    for(itr=data.iterator();itr.hasNext();)
    {%>
        <tr>
            <% String s= (String) itr.next(); %> 
            <td><%=s %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>

     <c:choose>
             <c:when test="${UserName!= 'admin'&& UserPassword!='admin'}">
        <form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_edit" id="edit_id" value="<%=s %>"/> 
             <input class="ignore" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
        </form>
        <form id="delete" action="DeleteRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" id="delete_id" value="<%=s %>"/>
            <input class="ignore" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="delete" name="delete"> </td>
        </form>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_edit" id="edit_id" value="<%=s %>"/> 
            <input class="ignore" type="submit"  value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
        </form>
        <form id="delete" action="DeleteRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" id="delete_id" value="<%=s %>"/>
            <input class="ignore" type="submit"  value="delete" name="delete"> </td>
        </form>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>     
        </tr>                   
    <%}%>
    </tbody>    
</TABLE>
```

The exception which I obtained after trying to delete is given as follows

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
DisplayData.DisplayData.doPost(DisplayData.java:85)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
DeleteRecord.DeleteRecord.doPost(DeleteRecord.java:61)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace please? also point out the line at number at which the xception happens.

Comment: There should be a particular line which produces exception in stacktrace

Comment: it will be very difficult to answer without seeing the stacktrace

Comment: At what line it is giving error, you should post stacktrace about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot forward after response has been committed in java servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496255/cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committed-in-java-servlet)

Comment: @JqueryLearner I have edited my question and posted the stack trace. For the deleting the record, it points the DisplayData line 85 which is "if (hiddenname.equals("login"))" and for updating the data the it shows line 216 which is "rd.forward(request, response);" within else if block of Update in DisplayDate servlet.

Comment: @A4L Please take look now and suggest me where I am making mistake. The exception points line 85 in DisplayData which is "if (hiddenname.equals("login"))" for deleting the data and for updating the data the it shows line 216 which is "rd.forward(request, response);" within else if block of Update in DisplayData servlet

Comment: @MH09 I have edited my question. Please take a look and guide me where I am making mistake.

Comment: @NathanHughes In this code I am not using multiple response.redirect. I checkfor the hiddenvalue and then asks the code to redirect to same page. it is not the duplicate of "Cannot forward after response has been committed in java servlet"

Comment: @Thileepan you have lots of form in the html and you have provided post method of a servlet.Can you tell me what is the servlet name of this post method.When you are doing `System.out.println(hiddenname);` so does anything prints in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
String hiddenname = request.getParameter("hiddenname");
```

may result in hiddenname beeing null (see [ServletRequest#getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29))

so when you do

```
if (hiddenname.equals("login"))
```

you get a NullPointerException

change it to [yoda notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) (it's a best pactice anyways)

```
if ("login".equals(hiddenname))
```

...

```
else if("update".equals(hiddenname))
```

`"login"` (a string literal in general) can never be null and you won't get a NPE. Or make sure that the request parameter is always present.

Comment: Thnak you for your suggestion. I tried your idea and it worked. I am able to update the record but the table is not loading the any data after the update and in the console shows null pointer exception and error points to rd.forward(request, response) with else if(update) block.

Comment: @Thileepan [ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)) may also return `null`, pllease check that the resource your trying to forward to is available.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I rectified my mistake. I need a small guidance from you. Only when username="admin" and password="admin" the buttons in displayrecord.jsp  enabled, for other username and password it is disabled. When I give admin as user credentials it displays records with buttons enabled but when I edit some record and update, the buttons are disabled because the user name and password entered during login is not passed to the else if block  update. How can I pass my login credentials to else if Block update the moment the user logins..Please guide me

Comment: @Thileepan You could put the username and password in the session, that way it will survive multiple requests until the user logs out (feature which you have to implement) or the session is invalidated by timeout.